# Should allowance amount have to be reduced on each successful call to transferFrom?

Tags: erc-20

I'm confused about [this issue](https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/20).

Description of `approve` function states

> Allow _spender to withdraw from your account, **multiple times**, **up to**
>   **the _value amount**.

If I'm understanding this correctly then it means that amount of what _spender is allowed to transfer will stay the same till this function is called again and _value changed.

But then description of `allowance` says

> the amount which _spender **is still** allowed to withdraw from _owner

Which makes me think that allowance gets reduced after each transfer? Or it just mens that even if _spender is allowed to spend 1000, he actually will be able to spend only x if the x is current balance and it is less than 1000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reality the spendable amount of tokens for `_spender` from `_owner` is obviously `min(balanceOf(address _owner),allowance(address _owner,address _spender))`, where `min` denotes the minimum function.

The amount of `allowance(address _owner,address _spender)` changes at each successful calling of these two functions:

1. `_owner` calls the `approve(address _spender, uint _value)` function or
2. `_spender` calls the `transferFrom(address _owner, address _to, uint _value)` function.

Comment: In short, it means that allowance can be spent and needs to be renewed?

Comment: Correct! Although not 100% sure what you mean by "needs to be renewed". If you mean that inside the approve or transferFrom functions your contract need to update the corresponding allowance value, then it is correct!

Comment: I mean that owner has to assign new allowance to spender.

Comment: Yes, sure! exactly